# How to log Wi-Fi network changes?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-monitoring

Is it possible to log, how, when and why, Wi-Fi network changes it's parameters like protocol, channel and so on?

Also would like to see client connections, base station switch, speed switch and so on.

Is it possible?

Comment: ive posted a workarround, i hope it could solve at least in a part your requirement.

Comment: Depending on your router: DD-WRT should have a logging facility within: http://dd-wrt.com/site/index

Comment: Since some of the things you've mentioned wanting to monitor are handled by the driver and not Windows it can't be done in a driver-agnostic way.

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 6):

**Method to save a log using a bat file and task scheduler by event trigger:**

Create a `.bat` example `wifilog.bat`

add this line in the bat

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid >> C:\dump.txt
```

or

```
netsh wlan show all >> C:\dump.txt
```

and save into a path:

**Then open Task Scheduler.**

1. Press Start Button [image: Start button] type run and press <kbd>Intro</kbd>.
2. Type the folowing in the run window `taskschd.msc` and press <kbd>Intro</kbd>.

[image: Run Task Scheduler]

3. Press *Action* and then *Create a Task*.

[image]

4. Select Triggers Tab and press *New*.

[image]

5. In the New Trigger Windows select *Begin the task On Event*.

[image]

6. And stead the showed parameters use this ones.

[image]

7. Then Press OK and go to the Actions Tab and press *New*, then select *Action: Start a program* and in the path input the path where you bat file was saved, then spress *OK*.

[image]

Press General tab and mark *Run with highest Privileges* to be sure to run the bat with Administrator Rights, then press ok and close task manager.

[image]

This method will execute the bat and save a dump or log in every Auto conection or disconection of Wireless Interface.

it will save a log with something like this in a text file.

[image]

> PD: Images have been taken as referencial from google, i could be
> posted mine but ive my Current SO in Spanish.
>
> Works in Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1
>
> **Not tested in Windows XP, Windows 10.**

Comment: Will this show how clients are trying to login to network and which of them are granted access and which fail?

Comment: P.S. Thank you for detailed answer but it concentrates on cron job creating but not about detailing oh what is happening in a network

Comment: @Dims you right ive folowed that you need In the op